# Help me with Slitherink puzzle (honeycomb) solution

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

I got stuck on this level (Honeycomb/Large/Hard/#12) and I always end up having issues with the part that I circled with red because it either wouldn't add up or there would be a space that's not connected, and I've tried different solutions as well. How I could solve that part or what's wrong with my solution so far?
I don't really need a solution for the whole puzzle just for around the circled part.

[It's an android app by Ejelta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ejelta.slitherlink.ads)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, let's label some edges:
>  [image]
>
> One of **A** and **B** must be an edge to continue the known loop (and the other is space). So **F** must be edge to have enough edges around the 4.
>
> One of **B** and **C** must be an edge to complete the 4, so **E** must be an edge to continue the loop.
>
> That gives us four known edges around the leftmost 4 (**E**, two for **F**, and one of **A**,**B**), so **D** must be a space.
>
> And that means that both **G** and **A** must be edges to have enough around the upper 4.
>
> So **B** is a space, and **C** is an edge.
>
>  That gets us to here:
>   [image]

> Zooming out and continuing with basic logic gets us to:
>  [image]
>  And as that has completed all the edges in the circled area without any contradictions so I'll stop there.

Comment: Nicely done. The 'basic knowledge deductions' can be formalized as topology with restrictions implied by knowing that in the end there is only a single connected string.